# Issue with adding abline to ROC curve using RStudio

Tags: r

I was trying to drow a ROC curve for the prediction I made using a classification tree. After plotting the curve with no issue, R wouldn't add abline.

The data looks like the following:

```
head(so)
 post.test.score messages forum.posts level.up
1          0.37       68           7       no
2          0.52       83          22      yes
3          0.42       81           7       no
4          0.56       94          14      yes
5          0.25       42          11       no
6          0.35       60          11       no
```

I first created a classification tree and then used this tree to generate a probability value that represents the probability of receiving the values of level.up.

```
c.tree1 <- rpart(level.up~post.test.score+messages+forum.posts, data=so, method="class")
so$pred <- predict(c.tree1, so, type = "prob")[,2]
```

As I went on to draw the ROC curve and add the abline, I received an error

```
library(ROCR)

pred.detail <- prediction(so$pred, so$level.up) 
plot(performance(pred.detail, "tpr", "fpr"))
abline(0, 1, lty = 2)
```

```
Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...): 
  plot.new has not been called yet
```

I read some posts about regression with similar problems, and realize that my problem might reside in the prediction itself, but I haven't been able to figure it out. What shall I do to add the abline successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Have you run all the codes?

I recreated a dataframe based on the data you provided, and I ran all the codes:

```
library(ROCR)
library(rpart)
so <- data.frame(post.test.score=c(0.37,0.53,0.42,0.56,0.25,0.35),
                 messages=c(68,83,81,94,42,60),
                 forum.posts=c(7,22,7,14,11,11),
                 level.up=c('no','yes','no','yes','no','no'))
c.tree1 <- rpart(level.up~post.test.score+messages+forum.posts, data=so, method="class")
so$pred <- predict(c.tree1, so, type = "prob")[,2]


pred.detail <- prediction(so$pred, so$level.up) 
plot(performance(pred.detail, "tpr", "fpr"))
abline(0, 1, lty = 2)
```

Here's the output, if that's what you are looking for:

[image: IMAGE1]